# Google Drive SDK Update (delete/insert) Owner Permission 500 Error in Try It Demo

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am developing an app that should provide a Google Apps Admin the ability to reassign ownership on files. Currently I am using the Google Drive SDK for .NET with C# code.

When I authenticate in the Google Drive SDK test demo at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert and fill in the `FileId` of a file belonging to the Admin and try to insert another owner from the same Google Apps domain I get a 500 internal server error. I'm using these values:

```
POST     https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B1Y4_hVm0vbESlZuZHhBemtjcXM/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer {MY_ACCESSTOKEN}
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "role": "owner",
 "type": "user",
 "value": "user@mydomain.com"
}
```

The "Try It" demo sets me up with the scopes

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

  to do this operation.

I am able to get a list of the permissions on the file by using the Try It demo authenticated as the same admin user, but I am unable to insert of delete owner permissions.

I picked the Google Drive SDK because it is newer and the Google Docs API was just depricated, but I would be willing to use whatever was the best tool for updating the ownership. I'm just looking for the straightest path to that goal.

Has anyone got the ownership update working? If so what tool did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed an internal bug for our engineers to investigate, however, I only managed to reproduce the issue when trying to share with an user from an external domain and not with one from the same domain.

Google Apps domain admins can prevent their users from changing ownership to external users, but in that case the API should not return a 500 and instead fail with a descriptive error message.

I'll update this answer as soon as I hear back from our investigation.

Comment: Just to be clear, the other user I am trying to pass ownership to is within the same Google Apps domain. 

I was wondering if it is because it is `owner`ship that I am trying to transfer. If I am not the `owner` of the document, but am the admin of the domain, I should be able to do this, no? In Google Docs API I would have to impersonate the `owner`. The Google Drive docs seem to imply that this is possible for domain admins.

Comment: The error seems to be due to the fact that the API is trying to delete the only owner of the file (and then create a new owner). As a workaround, can you check if the error still occurs if you 1) share the document with the other user as writer and then 2) set the other user as owner?

Comment: I had been getting the Error 500 when adding a role `owner` for a user who was already a `writer`. So that was while adding a second owner who was a writer. I also got it when attempting to delete the only owner in preparation for adding a new owner.

Now, just through the web demo "Try it" page, when I use the permission update with `{"role": "owner"}`, and this is on a user who is already a writer, I still get the Error 500. I tried the Patch too with the same results. 

Is this process working for other people? Could it be some setting on my domain?

Comment: I can update a `writer` to a `reader`. I can insert a `writer` or `reader` and I can delete a `writer` or `reader`. But when I try to insert a second `owner` or delete the `owner` or update the role of the `owner` permission I get a "500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: I have upgraded the account to a business account, thinking that might be the difference. It still does not work. I am not able to transfer even my own documents to another user within the domain by using the demo web app (APIs Explorer). I did find the Google Drive Ownership Transfer Tool, which allows me to transfer all documents, including PDF's, from one user to another within the domain. So there is no real security restriction from transferring someone else's files (files I  am not the owner of). No restriction when done in bulk.

Comment: We are still investigating this bug and working on a fix, thanks for your patience

Comment: FYI, I ran into the same issue, error 500 when I try to transfer the ownership to another user. I use a service account, .....@developer.gserviceaccount.com.

Comment: Also FYI, this feature is working fine in Google Documents List API for the same domains and accounts. No problemo.

Comment: I am going to mark this as answered, since it answered my question.

Comment: Hi Claudio, any news on this issue? Changing the ownership still throws a 500 error.

Comment: I also have the same issue, the new owner I'm trying to add does not belong to the same domain. Isn't there a solution to that user do not need to be in the same domain?

Comment: Hi, @ClaudioCherubino, any updates on this issue? I met the same problem when I tried use APIv2 to change ownership with domain admin account.

Answer (score 0):

using transferOwnership flag solved the problem for me.

in python api client, you can do:

```
service.permissions().patch(
        fileId=doc.drive_id, permissionId=permission_id,
        body=patched_permission, transferOwnership=True).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem several months ago. And I retried it yesterday ands it seems working now. It seems Google engineer already fixed the problem.

Hope it start working for you too.