# Google Drive Insert Permissions python 500 internal server error

Tags: google-api-python-client

this question is similar to:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471180/frequently-http-500-internal- error-with-google-drive-api-drive-files-get
 Though there is no answer for the 500 internal server error.

I am using Google Drive (python) to iterate through all of my files and change permissions on each file. I get responses like:
An error occurred: 
    https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/12345CuV3wBsvZDM3ZmRjNWQtMWZkNC00NzQzLTg2MzMtM2IyY2Q0YWU1OTll/permissions?alt=json returned "Internal Error">

My code is pretty cookie-cutter from google's examples, and is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from apiclient import errors
import httplib2
import pprint
import logging
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.client import FlowExchangeError
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
# Path to client_secrets.json which should contain a JSON document such as:
#   {
#     "web": {
#       "client_id": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]]",
#       "client_secret": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET]]",
#       "redirect_uris": [],
#       "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
#       "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
#     }
#   }
CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = '<PATH/TO/CLIENT_SECRETS.JSON>'
SCOPES = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
# Add other requested scopes.
]

class GetCredentialsException(Exception):
  """Error raised when an error occurred while retrieving credentials.

  Attributes:
    authorization_url: Authorization URL to redirect the user to in order to
                       request offline access.
  """

  def __init__(self, authorization_url):
    """Construct a GetCredentialsException."""
    self.authorization_url = authorization_url


class CodeExchangeException(GetCredentialsException):
  """Error raised when a code exchange has failed."""


class NoRefreshTokenException(GetCredentialsException):
  """Error raised when no refresh token has been found."""


class NoUserIdException(Exception):
  """Error raised when no user ID could be retrieved."""

def update_permission(service, file_id, permission_id, new_role):
  """Update a permission's role.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to update permission for.
    permission_id: ID of the permission to update.
    new_role: The value 'owner', 'writer' or 'reader'.

  Returns:
    The updated permission if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  try:
    # First retrieve the permission from the API.
    permission = service.permissions().get(
        fileId=file_id, permissionId=permission_id).execute()
    permission['role'] = new_role
    return service.permissions().update(
        fileId=file_id, permissionId=permission_id, body=permission).execute()
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
  return None  

def retrieve_all_files(service):
  """Retrieve a list of File resources.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
  Returns:
    List of File resources.
  """
  result = []
  page_token = None
  while True:
    try:
      param = {}
      if page_token:
        param['pageToken'] = page_token
      files = service.files().list(**param).execute()

      result.extend(files['items'])
      page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
      if not page_token:
        break
    except errors.HttpError, error:
      print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
      break
  return result

def retrieve_permissions(service, file_id):
  """Retrieve a list of permissions.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to retrieve permissions for.
  Returns:
    List of permissions.
  """
  try:
    permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
    return permissions.get('items', [])
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
  return None



def insert_permission(service, file_id, value, perm_type, role):
  """Insert a new permission.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to insert permission for.
    value: User or group e-mail address, domain name or None for 'default'
           type.
    perm_type: The value 'user', 'group', 'domain' or 'default'.
    role: The value 'owner', 'writer' or 'reader'.
  Returns:
    The inserted permission if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  new_permission = {
      'value': value,
      'type': perm_type,
      'role': role
  }
  try:
    return service.permissions().insert(
        fileId=file_id, body=new_permission).execute()
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
  return None



def login(clientID, clientSecret, clientCode=0):
    # Copy your credentials from the APIs Console
    CLIENT_ID     = clientID        
    CLIENT_SECRET = clientSecret

    # Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes
    OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

    # Redirect URI for installed apps
    REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
    #REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost'

    # Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    if not clientCode:
        print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
        code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

    else:
        print 'Client code supplied'
        code = clientCode 

    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

    # Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
    http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

allFilesDictionary = retrieve_all_files(drive_service)
file = open('file3.txt', 'a')
for f in allFilesDictionary:
    fileID            = f['id']
    permissionsIDList = retrieve_permissions(drive_service, fileID)
    pidl = permissionsIDList[0]
    #for pidl in permissionsIDList:
    #It is a list of dictionaries.....
    #for p in pidl:
    #   file.write(fileID + '\t\t' + p + ' value is' + p['id'] + '\n')
    #Change permissions of ID...
    ####"owner"
    ####permissionsIDList["userPermission"]["id"]
    ####"me" gives 500 "Http 500 Internal server error" ... empty oauth_callback value while request_token ... give webaddress
    #permissionsResource = update_permission(drive_service, fileID, "me", "reader")

    insert_permission(drive_service, fileID, "me", "user", "reader")

file.close()

clientid    ='1234567872174.apps.googleusercontent.com'
clientsecret='abcdefgh3VXUu5EaJvO9BExc'

login(clientid, clientsecret)
```

Going with Claudio's advice to 'add permissions' instead of 'insert permissions' changes the code to the following:

```
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
userNameAtGmailCom = 'PersonAEmailAddress@gmail.com'
password           = 'PersonAPassword'
personToShareWith  = "PersonB@gmail.com"
def login(userNameAtGmailCom, password, personToShareWith): 
    client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
    client.ClientLogin(userNameAtGmailCom, password)
    documents_feed = client.GetDocumentListFeed()
    for document_entry in documents_feed.entry:
        print document_entry.title.text
        scope = gdata.docs.Scope(value=personToShareWith, type='user')
        role = gdata.docs.Role(value='reader')
        acl_entry = gdata.docs.DocumentListAclEntry(scope=scope, role=role)
        created_acl_entry = client.Post(acl_entry, document_entry.GetAclLink().href,     converter=gdata.docs.DocumentListAclEntryFromString)
login(userNameAtGmailCom, password, personToShareWith)
```

This sends PersonB an email saying that PersonA has shared a file with them. Does this mean that when I can run an App from PersonB that will let personB's app read person A's files?

Comment: Do you think it is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558808/google-drive-sdk-update-delete-insert-owner-permission-500-error-in-try-it-dem/ ?

Comment: No. The reason I say this is because he/she says "I can update a writer to a reader". Whereas, I cannot update the file to be read. I just get the 500 internal server error.

Comment: I think it is similar in the sense that you are also trying to update the permissions of the only owner. In fact, you have no issues if you add permissions instead of updating them, right?

Comment: Hi Claudio, So I tried your suggestion and did 'add permissions' instead of 'insert permissions' - which requires the gdata library. So this changes my code (below) and allows me to 'share' documents from user A with user B. I have put in the code to do this below. I'm not sure if it is what I am trying to achieve though which is: I would like user B to have 'read' permissions through an App.

Comment: I would like to solve this problem using OAuth authentication and not logging in with the users name and password. So I havent closed this topic yet. Is it because I did not enter a value forCLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = '<PATH/TO/CLIENT_SECRETS.JSON>