# Google Drive Service account view/delete documents

Tags: google-drive-api

I have successfully been able to auto create documents via a service account. The service account is the owner of the created documents atm and I have shared the documents with several users.

My question is how can i view and delete these created documents in one place? I have tried adding a user permission with type 'owner' but that does not work and the user does not have access to the document.

Can I login as the service account and view and manage the documents from the google drive UI?

Thanks

Comment: When you change the owner, do you run itno this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558808/google-drive-sdk-update-delete-insert-owner-permission-500-error-in-try-it-dem/12562504#comment21037116_12562504

Comment: How can i change document ownership using php?

Comment: If you use a service account, and you do not add a service account user, I believe you can't. Did you check the link I posted?

Comment: Meaning, if I use Java and the drive.file scope, I cannot change the ownership using the API. I assume the same goes for PHP. I add a service account user when I build the drive service, this user becomes the owner. In your case I think you should delete the document via the API.